# How can I have a low value and a high value in a variable

Tags: python

Okay so my code is `PDMG = round(Mage['stats']['PStrength'] * .50)` so what I want to do is have the .50 as the minimum value and then have it multiply the same thing by .75, what do I do? Basically what I want is a minimum damage and a maximum damage, its for a a battle system

Comment: It is not clear what you actually want. You should elaborate your question a bit.

Comment: It's not to me clear either.
Are you looking for two values? If it is necessarily in one line, you might use lambda which returns tuple: `PDMG = (lambda x: (x*0.50, x*0.75))(Mage['stats']['PStrength'])`. It's a more functional way, I am not sure if I would prefer that over defining a proper function...

Comment: ternary operators are especially easy in Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: @kortfa I'll try your idea and see if it works out how im hoping for

Comment: @kotrfa your way worked how I wanted it to, but is there anyway I can get it to round the numbers?

Comment: @user5675699 `PDMG = (lambda x: (round(x*0.50), round(x*0.75)))(Mage['stats']['PStrength'])`

Comment: @kortfa Thanks for the help, it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can make two separate variables for it:

```
minPDMG = round(Mage['stats']['PStrength'] * .50)
maxPDMG = round(Mage['stats']['PStrength'] * .75)
```

Comment: I'll try your's first real quick